# How to add new html file in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have added an html file to my phonegap project to get the image to fire out, here have used jquery to do this. I get this error in the log:

> 09-03 16:54:42.154: E/Web Console(1049): ReferenceError: Can't find
>   variable: Swiper at
>   file:///android_asset/www/views/13-threshold.html:90

at this line

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    pagination: '.pagination',
    paginationClickable: true,
    moveStartThreshold: 100
})
```

I have used all the css and js files correctly, since I'm new to this I'm not able to find out the exact reason for the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

always give the reference directly in www folder, dont create the subfolder within www and then paste the code.instead of this android_asset/www/views/ try by this android_asset/www. so even this might be the reason for your reference issue

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Swiper isn't defined. Try defining it or including the relevant file. Also check the order in which the Javascript is called in the HTML, make sure the file that defines the object Swiper is included before the:

`var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{

    pagination: '.pagination',

    paginationClickable: true,

    moveStartThreshold: 100

})`